# This election is currently in the notstarted phase

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

[Did you mean 'This election has not started yet'?](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4)

[image]

Comment: Clearly the nots have been tarted...how can you not get that? Hmmm, tarted nots...

Comment: I don't always enjoy nots, but when I do, they *have* to be tarted.

Comment: I tend to oscillate between tarted and nottarted nots.

Comment: @J.Steen Not nottarted nots??!

Comment: For those mellow days.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fix for this is in the notbuiltyet phase.

Update:

The fix for this is in the fixed phase.